# Escape The Strange, Code-Filled Cave

Tags: logical-deduction, password, code

You awake in a weird cave with something strange written on the wall. You find a small piece of paper on a rock. It says the following:

*Solving each code and entering it into the password entering device, or the P.E.D. for short, will unlock the next room in the cave.*

**Rules:**

1. I will only accept answers which fully explain their reasoning for EVERYTHING.
2. If your answer comes up at about the same time as another person's, I will accept the answer based on quality of your work. (Note: I will still upvote both)
3. Note that it will get very difficult, and some stages may feel impossible to solve, but I bet somebody will solve it, because someone always solves it on PuzzlingSE, and everyone here is awesome at puzzles!
4. There's technically nothing stopping you from going to a room you aren't on, so I want you to pinky promise to me that you won't. ;)
5. Codes are in **bold**

*Good Luck!*

**Room 9 Hint:**

> This has something to do with morse code.

=========================================================================

**Room #1**:

> A sign above the P.E.D. says **eerht-ytfif** and **.retal lufesu eb yam siht**

**Room #2:**

> You see lots of letters on the wall that say **XXIV**. You also see a carving that says "xis kcab evom"

**Room #3:**

> Carvings on the wall say **Tjyuz**.

**Room #4:**

> You see a sign hanging from the wall that says **Bismuth**.

**Room #5:**

> You talk to a man who says "*I'm a prisoner here too. Here, take this slip of paper I found 3 rooms ago. I'm not sure what it means, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.*" You look at the paper and see the text: **vrayDBO**

**Room #6:**

> You a long plaque taking the whole left wall that says **010101000111011101100101011011100111010001111001001011010101010001110111 01101111**.

**Room #7:**

> You find a man, no doubt crazy from being locked in the cave, say that he knows the code, but will only tell you in riddle form. He says **The code is of 5 numbers, and each number is different. The sum of all its numbers equals 21. The second number is twice the third, the third is twice the first, and the first is twice the fourth. The fifth number is twice the difference of the third number minus the fourth number.**

**Room #8:**

> You find a massive wall with a massive plaque that says: **00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000**. You wonder what this long string of numbers could mean. You see another smaller plaque that says **URURURURURUXZ**

**Room #9:**

> A man says: "*I think the last room is next. I just can't solve this puzzle! Here, you try it!*" The man hands you a slip of paper which says **VI AO CU I B NIJL EGKHJI UIO E AOEH E GA** You are utterly confused and do not know what this could even mean.

**Room #10**

> There is a sign that says: *You have gone this far, and solved many puzzles, but now you are nearing the end. If you have paid close attention, then the following should be easy.* Just as you finish reading it, a panel pops up from the wall. It shows one code: **OUR 5mooR 85 11100110011101101001011001101110001101101111011011001110 QVAAMFT**. If you can find a way to solve it then you and your new friends can get out of the weird cave and to safety! The P.E.D. comes up through the wall, but this time you can enter letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Are partial answers okay to be posted (all three so far are partial)?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine

Comment: I'm glad to see people are liking this! It took a while to make!

Comment: @Xandawesome It's pretty gruesome to solve too, especially Room 8!

Comment: Excellent puzzle, very creative. Kudos to you!

Comment: Just seeing the title, I thought this was about a computer programmer looking for a new job. :-)

Comment: Lol XD That sounds about right!

Comment: I would like to go ahead and thank everyone who participated for participating! Rooms 9 and 10 seem to be pretty hard ones; I wonder who'll solve them first. Remember, I'll only accept answers with the full answers on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Room 1:

> Read the words backward.
>  Additional message: **this may be useful later.**
>  Password: fifty-three (**53**)

Room 2:

> Roman numerals: XXIV=24
>  Additional message (read backward): **move back six.**
>  Password: **24**

Room 3:

> Caesar cipher with key 53 (from room 1), or 1 (mod 26). Shift backwards.
>  Password: sixty (**60**)

Room 4:

> Periodic table of elements: Bismuth is element 83.
>  Password: **83**

Room 5:

> In room 2, use the additional message for Caesar shift 6 letters backward.
>  Message: plusXVI, or plus 16
>  Password: 24 + 16 = **40**

Room 6:

> Binary
>  Password: twenty-two (**22**)

Room 7:

> Assume password has format $xyzab$.
>  We are given the following:
>  $$x+y+z+a+b=21$$
>  $$y=2z$$
>  $$z=2x$$
>  $$x=2a$$
>  $$b=2(z-a)$$
>  Therefore,
>  $$y=2z=4x=8a$$
>  $$z=2x=4a$$
>  $$b=2(4a-a)=6a$$
>  So,
>  $$x+y+z+a+b=2a+8a+4a+a+6a=21a=21$$
>  We get $a=1$.
>  Password: **28416**

Room 8:

> Please see the excellent answers given by [MisterEman22](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15805/12109), [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15808/12109), and [HDE 226868](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15803/12109). I couldn't find a binary translator willing to take such a long string of numbers!
>
>  Take the binary text and convert that to text. Convert that to text again. Do it again to get number 57.
>  Password: **57**

Room 9:

> [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15808/12109) got this one first (as usual):
>  Turn each vowel into a dot and each consonant into a dash. Translate morse to text.
>  Morse: `-.  ..  -.  .  -  -.--  .----.  ...  .  ...-  .  -.`
>  Password: ninety?seven (**97**)
>  Note: there was probably a mistake in encoding the character `-`. In morse, that should be `-....-`, which was written as `.---.`.

Room 10:

> The encryption method used previously were:
>  - backwards
>  - roman numerals
>  - caesar cipher (1 and 6 letters backwards)
>  - periodic table of elements
>  - binary (1 and 3 times)
>  - math/algebra
>  - morse
>
>  One part at a time:
>  **OUR**: U (morse)
>  **5mooR**: Room5 (backwards)
>  **85**: At (element astatine, which is number 85)
>  **11100110011101101001011001101110001101101111011011001110**: solving (backwards, binary)
>  **QVAAMFT**: PUZZLES (caesar cipher backwards by 1)
>
>  **Room5** decoded (credit to [Zandar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/escape-the-strange-code-filled-cave/15802?noredirect=1#comment53246_15802) for this one): The answer for Room 5 is 40. In roman numerals, that would be **XL**, or **excel** in english.
>
>  Together, that would be: **U XL At solving PUZZLES**
>
>  In english, that would be: **You excel at solving puzzles**.

Comment: Good job except for room 2 the "move back six" was the hint for room 5 for the cipher, not the room 2 number. The room 2 number is 40.

Comment: Oh, LOL, I meant room 5 was 40. Room 2 is then 24.

Comment: Something like that, yes, but not exactly. You're getting close!

Comment: Don't worry. you'll get it!

Comment: Sure! I'm glad someone is still doing it! I'll add a hint now

Comment: You are crazy... No I'm kidding but wow you are one word off! The only word that is off is the word "crazy"! Keep thinking about room 5! Who will get it first???

Comment: Nope! All you need to solve the last word is room 5!

Comment: The result isn't a number, but *Hint* *Hint* it comes from one... ;)

Comment: You mean, it's a number in english form, or we have to take the english form and do something to it?

Comment: Just think about it... You don't need that many hints! You're so close! Don't do anything to it that much! Just think about it! You'll figure it out!

Comment: The solution to room 5 is 40, which is XL in Roman numerals (which are also used in room 5). The complete message is therefore "U XL (excel) At solving PUZZLES."

Comment: @Zandar Ahh! That makes sense. You *do* excel at solving puzzles.

Comment: @Xandawesome How does it look now?

Comment: Yay! Looks like you got it :-D

Comment: Nope, that's not it. JK that''s it good job! I'm glad someone finally got it! You're free! For now...

Comment: Hmm... This got some good votes... I do wonder... Will a sequel be released...?

Comment: @Xandawesome Tell me if you decide to make a sequel. I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: The question is not IF there will make a sequel, but WHEN it'll be released... ;)

Answer (score 6):

**Room #1**

> Password is **53**.
> Read the messages backwards to get "fifty-three" and "this may be useful later."

**Room #2**

> Password is **24**.
> The letters on the wall are 24 in Roman numerals; the carving backwards is "move back six" which will be used later.

**Room #3**

> Password is **60**.
> Caesar-shift "Tjyuz" back 1 place (T goes to S, J goes to I, Y to X, U to T, Z to Y) to get "Sixty".

**Room #4**

> Password is **83**.
> Bismuth has atomic number 83 on the periodic table.

**Room #5**

> Password is **40**.
> Three rooms ago the password was 24; Caesar-shift "vrayDBO" six places backwards (V goes to P, R goes to L, A to U, Y to S, D to X, B to V, O to I) to get "plusXVI", so we add XVI=16 to 24 to get 40.

**Room #6**

> Password is **22**.
> Convert the given number from binary ASCII code to characters (01010100 goes to T, 01110111 goes to w, 01100101 to e, 01101110 to n, 01110100 to t, 01111001 to y, 00101101 to - (hyphen), 01010100 to T, 01110111 to w, 01101111 to o) to get "Twenty-Two".

**Room #7**

> Password is **28416**.
> We need five numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ summing to 21 such that $b=2c,c=2a,a=2d$ - giving $b=8d$ and so, since $b<10$, we have $d=1,a=2,c=4,b=8$ - and also $e=2(c-d)=6$, so the answer is 28416. Check: 2+8+4+1+6=21.

**Room #8**

> Password is **57**.
> All the numbers on the massive plaque are ASCII code for either 0 or 1 or space. Converting these ASCII codes to characters, we get 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110000. All of these are also ASCII code for either 0 or 1 or space, so we can perform the same conversion to get 01000110 01101001 01100110 01110100 01111001 00101101 01010011 01100101 01110110 01100101 01101110. Now convert these from ASCII codes to characters to get "Fifty-Seven". (I'm not sure yet what the significance of "URURURURURUXZ" is.)

**Room #9**

> Password is **97**.
> Treat each consonant as a dash and each vowel as a dot in Morse code (VI goes to .- goes to N, AO goes to .. goes to I, CU goes to .- goes to N, etc.) to turn "VI AO CU I B NIJL EGKHJI UIO E AOEH E GA" into "ninety-seven".

**Room #10**

> *[Work in progress]*
> "5mooR" is "Room5" backwards. Turning the binary code backwards gives 01110011 01101111 01101100 01110110 01101001 01101110 01100111; converting this from ASCII codes to characters gives "solving". "QVAAMFT" Caesar-shifted back by 1 is "PUZZLES".

Comment: You're doing good! You made an attempt of 9 and 10 and pointed out the "URURURURURUXZ" from room 8. You can do it!

Comment: @Xandawesome Edited on Room 10 - I've solved most of it now!

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: @Xandawesome Still can't make sense of "OUR Room5 85 solving PUZZLES" though...

Comment: Remember, it says that you had to pay attention through the rooms. Look back and see if you can find something! HINT: You haven't solved room 9 yet, so that may hinder you a bit. ;)

Comment: @Xandawesome Room 9: "Via Oh, see you! I be Nigel, e.g. cage jay I. You I owe [...]" Re. looking back through the rooms, what about "this may be useful later"?

Comment: Lol the room 9 comment isn't right but it just goes to show that you can make up about just anything in your head while trying to solve a puzzle! As for the "this may be useful later" I cannot tell you if you need that or not.

Comment: I solved all 8 rooms so far and I'm also stuck on room #9. In addition, I solved "URURURURURUXZ" by ceaser shifting it by 6 to give: "OLOLOLOLOLORT" read backword "TROLOLOLOLOLO". I don't know if it was a joke by @Xandawesome concerning room#8 that he was trolling and we should use ASCII many times or we will use it for next two rooms.

Comment: @ChadiAbouSleiman If you solved some of them feel free to post an answer! ;)

Comment: I solved the first 8 rooms without looking at the answers posted, but was stuck on room #9. I've been staring at it since then trying all the decoding techniques I know but none of them gave me something meaningful or even close to something.

Comment: @Xandawesome OK, solved room 9 thanks to the new hint!

Comment: Yay! That took a long time! I'm glad someone finally solved room 9! Wow, that just shows you the power of a hint! Good luck on room 10!

Comment: @Xandawesome Does 5mooR decode to "good" by any chance? Then the answer to Room 10 could be "O U R good At solving PUZZLES" :-D

Comment: That's good but that's not actually it! You're really close though! Where'd you get the "good" from? Also, for the 5mooR it's Room5 backwards and you do have to look at room 5 itself for the word. I have a feeling it's going to finally be solved!

Answer (score 3):

## The first 8 Rooms

**Room 1:**

> "eerht-ytfif and .retal lufesu eb yam siht" becomes **fifty-three** and **this may be useful later.** Simply write them in reverse.

**Room 2:**

> "XXIV" is **24** in Roman numerals. "xis kcab evom" backwards is "move back six", so 24 - 6 is **18**.

**Room 3:**

> Shift each letter on "Tjyuz" one backward (e.g. "b" would be "a"). This gives you **Sixty**.

**Room 4:**

> [Bismuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth) is element number **83**.

**Room 5:**

> The paper was found three rooms ago, in Room 2, where "move back six" was found. Move each letter back six spaces (e.g. "g" would be "a". "vrayDBO" becomes "plus XVI", which is **plus 16**.

**Room 6:**

> That sequence of digits is in binary; it means **Twenty-Two**

**Room 7:**

> Just use algebra here. Bypassing writing it all out, if the numbers are a,b,c,d,e, then d=1, a=2, b=8, c=4, and e=6, giving **2-8-4-1-6**. Set up a system of equations, where a+b+c+d+e+21, and go from there.

**Room 8:**

> Translate the string from binary to normal numbers, then translate *that* from binary to normal numbers. You get **Fifty-seven**.

Comment: Good job except for room 2 the "move back six" was the hint for room 5 for the cipher, not the room 2 number. The room 2 number is 40.

Comment: @Xandawesome Thanks, but why 40, and not 24?

Comment: Oh, LOL, I meant room 5 was 40. Room 2 is then 24.

Comment: Lol good luck, room 9 is a tricky one!

Comment: Also, your "Room 5" answer is unclear. What do you mean by that? The answer can only be in number form.

Answer (score 2):

Room 1:

> 53

Explanation:

> The sign says fifty-three backwards, and also "This may be useful later."

Room 2:

> 24

Explanation:

> The roman numeral XXIV is 24.

Room 3:

> 60

Explanation:

> Changing *Tjyuz* to the letter before each letter (rotation cipher using -1) gives us *Sixty*

Room 4:

> 83

Explanation:

> The atomic number for the element Bismuth is 83.

Room 5:

> 34

Explanation:

> Using the hint from "three rooms back" (room 2) of "move back six", we use a rotation cipher of -6 to turn vrayDBO into plusXVI which gives us plus 16. So we take the answer of 24 from room 2 and add 16, to get 40.

Room 6:

> 22

Explanation:

> Decoding the given numbers from binary to ASCII gives "Twenty-Two"

Room 7:

> 28416

Explanation:

> We start knowing that the number has 5 digits that are all different. Looking from the end, the first number is twice the fourth, so the first must either be 2, 4, 6, or 8 and the fourth must either be 1, 2, 3 or 4.
> The third is twice the first, meaning the third must now be 2, 4, 6, or 8. This leaves the first to either be 2 or 4 and the fourth to be 1 or 2.
> The second is twice the third, meaning it can be 2, 4, 6, or 8. This leaves the third to be 2 or 4, so the first must be 2, and the fourth must be 1, which makes the third 4 and the second 8.
> So right now our number is 2841_. The fifth must be 2 times third minus fourth, so 2(4-1) = 6, so the number is 28416, which sums to 21 so it fits.

Room 8:

> 57

Explanation:

> Converting from binary to text gives us another binary code. Converting again gives us another shorter binary code. Converting a third time gives us text of "fifty-seven"

Room 9:

> Working on it

Explanation:

> Given the characters per word of the given text (2 2 2 1 1 4 3 1 3 1 2) I would say that it isn't a 1:1 conversion of characters. I'm not sure what that points me toward, but vigenere/caesar don't seem to be helping at all. Also looking into binary conversion and reversing the binary conversion doesn't seem to give anything useful.

Room 10:

> Working on it

Explanation:

> 

Comment: Good job except for room 2 the "move back six" was the hint for room 5 for the cipher, not the room 2 number. The room 2 number is 40.

Comment: Oh, LOL, I meant room 5 was 40. Room 2 is then 24.